# Is it possible to customize the look and feel of the Forward to a Friend Default Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, html5, css3

Is it possible to customize the look and feel of the Forward to a Friend Default MC Page?

Thanks!

Comment: If you could explain the use case, maybe we could come up with a better solution. Here’s an article about Brand Builder: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/08/25/customize-your-marketing-cloud-account-with-your-companys-branding/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than through the usual [BrandBuilder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_brandbuilder.htm&type=5) colours and logo, not really. Certain levels of Support have access to Manage to alter the Brand Tags that define much of the page design, but getting Salesforce Support or CSG to update that design for you would be a trial. The way the page is put together is arcane, Manage isn't a CMS, it'd involve a bit of hacking around and what you're dealing with is little understood in the Services arm of Salesforce. You would need to consider putting together a custom CloudPage to fulfil the purpose, more likely. And then you'd need to consider the legality of FTAF in your jurisdiction and a somewhat limited ROI.